# Defining functions using javascript object literal notation

Tags: javascript, json, function, object-literal

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-do-in-javascript) describes how you can use Javascript obect literal notation to describe a collection of functions for example:

```
var crudActions = {
    create : function () {
          ... 
    }
    read : function () {
          ...
    }
}
```

Is there a name for this pattern? And is there an advantage to using this approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600130/javascript-advantages-of-object-literal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you just did is give your functions a "namespace". your functions are now a "collection of related tasks"

namespacing means that is your functions don't "live" in the global scope anymore (and thus avoid polluting/overwriting it with other functions). so all your functions can be addressed from the "namespace" and not worry if another function has the same name as it (like another `create()`).

like say in your app you have a database and a view. both can do a "create" but having 2 `create()` functions is not possible. creating weird names like `createDatabase()` and `createView()` is just not organized. thus you create namespaces so they can be called `database.create()` and `view.create()` - makes more sense.

Answer (score -2):

create the object and define the property and value

```
var personA = {
    name:"personName",
    age : 23,
    sex : "Male",

    info:function() {
        console.log(name + ": "+age+ ": "+sex);
    }
};
```

declaration method of variable and function in object. This method mostly used in closure.