# Trying to better under stand the object literal pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the init function of the myFeature object below there is the line `$.extend(myFeature.config, config)`. My background makes me wonder why the line isn't $.extend(this.config,config)? Wouldn't **this** refer to the parent object in the body of the function?

If that is not the case, I think I would want to use the revealing module pattern, if I understand it well enough, because I can do **var self = this;** and refer to self throughout the properties of myFeature. I don't understand how in the object literal pattern the init property has access to myFeature within the function. It seems myFeature is globally scoped and all its properties and itself can be accessed by anyone at anytime, I know this is the nature of javascript and I understand a bit but I am thinking the revealing module pattern will give me private/public access that makes me sleep better at night.

```
var myFeature = {
    config : {
        wrapper : '#myFeature',
        container : 'div',
        urlBase : 'foo.php?item='
    },

    init : function(config) {
        $.extend(myFeature.config, config);
        $(myFeature.config.wrapper).find('li').
            each(function() {
                myFeature.getContent($(this));
            }).
            click(function() {
                myFeature.showContent($(this));
            });
    },

    buildUrl : function($li) {
        return myFeature.config.urlBase + $li.attr('id');
    },

    getContent : function($li) {
        $li.append(myFeature.config.container);
        var url = myFeature.buildUrl($li);
        $li.find(myFeature.config.container).load(url);
    },

    showContent : function($li) {
        $li.find('div').show();
        myFeature.hideContent($li.siblings());
    },

    hideContent : function($elements) {
        $elements.find('div').hide();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() { myFeature.init(); });
```

Comment: you could use this.config if you want.

Comment: A very good explanation is waiting for you, [Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600130/javascript-advantages-of-object-literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder why `$.extend(myFeature.config, config)` isn't `$.extend(this.config,config)`? Wouldn't `this` refer to the parent object in the body of the function?

Yes, since you're calling it with `myFeature.init()` it would work - see [how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). However, you can strife for safety - by explicitly refering to `myFeature` it would also allow

```
$(document).ready(myFeature.init);
```

> I don't understand how in the object literal pattern the init property has access to myFeature within the function. It seems myFeature is globally scoped and all its properties and itself can be accessed by anyone at anytime.

Yes. The `myFeature` variable is in global scope and could even be overwritten by a completely different object. The reavealing module pattern would have a local-scoped `self` variable, which could not be manipultated.

> I am thinking the revealing module pattern will give me private/public access that makes me sleep better at night

Yes. If you like it better, you should implement it :-)