# When to use an IIFE vs Object Literals?

Tags: javascript

I'm about to start building a small javascript module for an app. I've been exposed to two different ways of organizing code: the object literal and the IIFE. I know that with the IIFE, all variables and functions remain private unless otherwise made public, but are there any other reasons why I would use that over the object literal?

Why would I use the object literal:

```
var gojiraSays = 'Toxic Garbage Island!!!'

var app = {

  printStuff: function(){
    console.log(gojiraSays)
  }

}
```

...over say the IIFE version:

```
var app = (function(){
  var gojiraSays = 'Toxic Garbage Island!!!'

  var yellGojira = function(){
    console.log(gojiraSays);
  }

  return{
    yellGojira: yellGojira
  }

}());

app.yellGojira();
```

Comment: This depends on too many different things. For example, if you intend for your module to be used with something like WebPack, the IIFE is completely redundant.

Comment: After the edit, yes, the advantage of wrapping in an IIFE is encapsulation (nothing else can mess with your `gojiraSays`). There's IIFE in other contexts (not as contrast to object literals), e.g. inside `for` or `while` loops to capture the value of local variables instead the variables themselves for async callbacks ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)).

Comment: these are two different things. IIFEs deal with encapsulation of (private) variables whereas Objects provide structure to combine/group things that belong together. IIFEs don't provide structure, and Objects don't provide encapsulation. Your question is like asking, wich to prefer: functions or variables? You'll need both, and you'll probably combine them.

Answer (score 2):

> Module Pattern

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600130/javascript-advantages-of-object-literal) answer to gain knowledge about advantages of using Object literal along with **Revealing Module Pattern** (RMP).

> IIFE

Refer [this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-using-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression) link to get information about advantages of using IIFE's for project structuring.

> My Suggestion

I will prefer using **RMP** as it enables you to efficiently *separate concerns* and will improve the *readability* at the same time.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. The stupidly-named "revealing module pattern" **uses** IIFEs, so how can you treat the two as somehow being alternatives?

Comment: This will help you answer your doubt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906662/javascript-design-pattern-difference-between-module-pattern-and-revealing-modul

Answer (score 1):

You should learn a third, better way of organizing modules, which is ES6 modules, which makes all this irrelevant.

```
// app.js
const gojiraSays = 'Toxic Garbage Island!!!'

export function printStuff() {
  console.log(gojiraSays)
}

// consumer.js
import {printStuff} from './app';

printStuff();
```

You will need a bit of infrastructure, such as a Babel transpilation step, to make this work.